# Remote delete inconsistently hits resource limit / timeout

Tags: sql, sql-server, timeout, sql-server-2014

My SQL Agent job runs every morning at 4 AM.  It has 10 steps.

The last few weeks, it has been failing a couple times a week on Step 3 with this error.

> The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "RemoteServerName"
>   reported an error.
>
> Execution terminated by the provider because a
>   resource limit was reached. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7399)
>
> Cannot fetch the rowset from OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server
>   "RemoteServerName". . [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7421)
>
> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "RemoteServerName" returned message "Query
>   timeout expired". [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 7412).   The step failed.

- When step 3 is successful, the duration is between 1 - 7 minutes.
- When step 3 fails, the duration is between 12 - 15 minutes.
- Both SQL Servers have 'Remote Query Timeout' set to 600 seconds ( 10 minutes ).

The entirety of Step 3, oddly enough, is just a simple DELETE statement.

```
DELETE FROM [RemoteServerName].DbNameHere.dbo.CompanyProductLink_Copy
```

1. If the timeout is set to 10 minutes, and the error says 'query timeout expired', why is the step duration varying between 12 and 15 minutes?
2. Is there a more efficient way to delete ~1,000,000 records from a remote table?

**I can pretty easily increase the timeout... I just want to understand**

Running SQL Server v12, on SSD's with 24GB RAM allocated.

Comment: [Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes) blogs about batch deletes if that interests you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can take time to delete a table.  Assuming you have no triggers or cascading foreign key references, then use `truncate table` instead:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [RemoteServerName].DbNameHere.dbo.CompanyProductLink_Copy;
```

This should be much faster than a `DELETE`.

Comment: When I run 'TRUNCATE TABLE', it immediately errors saying "Database 'DbNameHere' does not exist.'.  However, when I run the 'DELETE FROM' the SQL runs.  Does TRUNCATE TABLE not work against Linked Servers?

Comment: Nevermind, just had to change the syntax around a bit..  EXEC [RemoteServerName].DbNameHere.sys.sp_executesql N'TRUNCATE TABLE CompanyProductLink_Copy';